# Using Path Animation in Windows 8 using XAML

Tags: xaml, animation, windows-8, .net-4.5

I would like to animate a UI control (an Image actually) over a Path provided.

It is looking that it is not possible to do it in Windows 8 using XAML although it was possible with .NET 4.5 as far as I could see from the below reference.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746981.aspx

My question is whether there is a work around that I can use to achieve my goal or get closer to it.

Comment: I have tried using Expression Blend to make the animation via XAML. I added several points to make the animation smoother. My desired path is a fixed parabolic curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinRT is very similar to Silverlight, so many Silverlight solutions can work in WinRT with minimal or no changes. This sample on CodeProject should give you DoubleAnimationUsingPath with little work.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30819/Animation-Along-a-Path-for-Silverlight

Comment: I looked at the code and it seems this is a bit complexer solution to my constrained problem. Sorry I forgot to mention that my path is fixed. I was hoping to get a way to realize the animation only using XAML.